# Displaying 5 digit entry_ids

Tags: channel-entries, formatting

Want to display entry_id's in a numeric list so they can be sorted with jquery plugins.

Heres current code to achieve this, basically adding appropriate amount of zeros before entry_id so all are 5 digits:

```
 Entry ID {if entry_id < '10'}0000{/if}{if entry_id < '100'}000{/if}{if entry_id < '1000'}00{/if}{if entry_id < '10000'}0{/if}{entry_id}
```

There has to be a cleaner way!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CE String](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string/user-guide/native_methods) native method of `str_pad` to pad the `{entry_id}` to a certain length:

```
{exp:ce_str:ing str_pad="5|0|:CONST:STR_PAD_LEFT"}{entry_id}{/exp:ce_str:ing}
```

Comment: No problem, remember to mark this answer as correct